Hardhat deploying issue
I got a deployment error and when I looked to other similar issues and their solutions, those are not working out for me.
Here’s the deploy command:
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost

Here’s the error:
Error during deployment: TypeError: tracking.deployed is not a function 

I tried to uninstall and install hardhat, ethers etc. I connected a node to MetaMask so what is the main problem that I have not solved yet?

deploy.js :
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    
    const Tracking = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Tracking");

    const tracking = await Tracking.deploy();
    
    await tracking.waitForDeployment(); 

    console.log(`Tracking deployed to: ${tracking.address}`);
    
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error during deployment:", error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});

hardhat version ^2.22.8 , ethers version ^6.13.2

Could you share your code in deploy.js? And what version of hardhat, ethers you are using?

Replace .deployed() with .waitForDeployment()
